# Depth of an array

Tags: java

If we are given an array `arr1` consisting of n integers, we can calculate the depth of it in the following way as in image.

[image: Image shows the formula to calculate depth]

The first line of input contains 3 integers n, a, b where n is the size of array.
The second line of input contains array elements. Now if the depth of array = a/b we need to print "yes" else "no".

I have tried to implement the following code:

```
public static void solve(int n, int a,int b, int[] arr) {
        String result = "";

        double depth = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            depth = (double)((double)(depth + arr[i]) + (double)(1 / arr[i + 1]));
        }

        double d = (double) a / b;

        if (depth == d) {
            result = "YES";
        } else {
            result = "NO";
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: ... and the problem is? Please create a [MRE]. A remark: "*`depth=(double)((double)(depth+arr[i])+(double)(1/arr[i+1]));`*" - This line is unreadable. Too much casting, to many parentheses. You should refactor this.

Comment: this formula could be easily computed recursively.

Comment: @michalk: I suspect it could be done iteratively from the far end of the array, too: loop from `arr[arr.length - 1]` to `arr[0]`, each time using `depth = arr[i] + 1.0 / depth`.

Comment: @JonSkeet for the input 2 4 1 3 1 I am getting No as output. It should be Yes

Comment: @michalk can you tell how?

Comment: @rahulnegi when running the code with that input I get "YES"

Comment: @Mureinik can you help me with the loop?

Comment: Yes, the code you've got is broken at the moment. I would suggest you use a debugger and a pencil/paper to work out what you *expect* it to do vs what results you actually get at each step.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have tried this loop but i am getting depth as 0.0                          for(int i=arr[arr.length-1];i>arr[0];i--)
        {
            
            depth=arr[i]+1.0/depth;
        }

Comment: No, that's not what I was suggesting. The idea is to go from the end of the array to the start. I think you really need to work through this with pen and paper, and a debugger - just copying code from someone else isn't going to help you.