# Calculate depth of array

Tags: algorithm

[image]

I want to calculate the depth of array as per the formula in the image.
I have implemented the following code but I am not able to get correct results.
Input contains the size of the array n and elements

```
depth=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {

            depth=depth+arr[i]+(1/arr[i+1]);
        }
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: this formula is not clear enough, please provide clear formula.

Comment: @NiVeR input contains an array of size n

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry what is unclear?

Comment: Is `arr` an array of float or double? I ask because `1/arr[i+1]` is integer math if arr is an array of integers.

Comment: it can be a recursion problem, as a recursion problem, always think about the base case, which is the last step. so if you wish to implement it iteratively, you need to go from n-1 to 0, not 0 to n-1

Comment: @harold it will be good to know both. I am learning to programme.

Comment: did you try my answer @SumeetNegi

Comment: For `n=3`, your code computes `arr[0] + 1/arr[1] + arr[1] + 1/arr[2]`, which is obviously wrong. (This gets much easier if you start at the bottom.)

Comment: @molbdnilo can you tell how to fix it?

Comment: @Thomas not getting correct result

Comment: the same question was asked yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912049/depth-of-an-array?noredirect=1#comment100368090_56912049

Comment: C++ and Java are completely different languages - retagged as algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

try this, its simplest to do with recursion -

```
static double calc_depth(int arr[], int i) {
    return arr[i] + (i<arr.length-1 ? + (1.0 / calc_depth(arr, i+1)) : 0.0);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] a = {2, 1};
    System.out.println(calc_depth(a, 0));
}
```

Comment: @SumeetNegi, I debugged it, try it now.

Comment: @harold that edge case is not resolvable unless you know the actual value of 1/0

Comment: it has passed 2 test cases. But 11 hidden cases are failing. Should all the values have to be taken as BigInteger?

Comment: @SumeetNegi what are constraints for this problem. escpecially the number limit

Comment: 1<=n<=50 and 1<= arr[¡] <= 1018 where arr[¡] is the ith element of the array @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a c++ editor now, but the idea is the same:
you can do this in your way, this is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def cal(arr):
    depth, n = 0.0, len(arr)
    # go from n - 1 to 0
    for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):  
        if depth == 0.0:
            depth = arr[i]
        else:
            depth = (arr[i] + 1.0 / depth)
    return depth


arr = [10, 20, 30]
print cal(arr)
```

As I mentioned in comment, if you wish to implement it iteratively, you need to go from n-1 to 0, not 0 to n-1, and you need to solve the base case.
Also, this one can be implemented in a recursive way as first answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the C++ has been removed in the meantime, so if you still want c++, here's almost an one-liner:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
double depth(const std::vector<double>& array){
    return std::accumulate(array.rbegin(),array.rend(),std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(),[](double s, double a){
        return a + 1.0/s;
    });
}

#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::vector<double> v{ 1.0,2.0,3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0};

    std::cout<<depth(v);
}
```

But you won't get very precise results for continued fractions due to the floating-point precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like :

```
double ans=0;
for(int i=n-1;i>1;i--){
    arr[i-1] = arr[i-1] + (double)(1/arr[i]);
    ans = arr[i-1];
}
```